# Pandoc can't get Locale/Encoding right with Hakyll and Gitlab CI

Tags: haskell, locale, gitlab-ci, pandoc, hakyll

I'm trying to use Gitlab Pages to automatically deploy my Hakyll blog, but I keep having problems with file encoding.

When building the pages, I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] /builds/jmite/hakyll/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux/lts-8.14/8.0.2/share/x86_64-linux-ghc-8.0.2/pandoc-citeproc-0.10.4.1/locales/locales-C-.xml: openBinaryFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)
```

My `.gitlab-ci.yaml` looks like this:

```
image: fpco/stack-build:lts-8.14


before_script:
  - LC_ALL=en_CA.UTF-8
  - LANG=en_CA.UTF-8
  - apt-get update && apt-get install xz-utils make
  - export STACK_ROOT=`pwd`/.stack
  - stack setup
  - stack install --only-dependencies
  - stack build

build:
  cache:
    paths:
      - _cache
      - .stack
  script:
    - stack exec site build
  except:
    - master

pages:
  cache:
    paths:
      - _cache
      - .stack
  script:
    - stack exec site build
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - public
  only:
    - master
```

I've tried adding locale information to my config:

```
  - LC_ALL=en_CA.UTF-8
  - LANG=en_CA.UTF-8
```

But then I get the following error:

```
/bin/bash: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_CA.UTF-8)
[ERROR] ./templates/default.html: hGetContents: invalid argument (invalid byte sequence)
```

How can I fix this? Is there a way to (1) change the encoding on mo local machine, and push to GitLab, so that the files will match whatever Pandoc is expecting, or (2) to configure the GitLab CI to work with them how they're encoded now?

When I open the files in vscode it says they are UTF-8. Are there ways to get more information about the encoding that might be causing problems?

Comment: You should try the [Hakyll google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/hakyll) if you don't get an answer here.

Comment: The error message suggests that en_CA locale is not available - you might need to generate it first: `locale-gen en_CA`